# Wrapping multiple AutoCloseables

Tags: java, autocloseable

`try`-with-resources is nice and all that, but it seems to me that it is still not sufficient for effective resource management when creating classes that wrap multiple `AutoCloseable` objects. For example, consider

```
import java.io.*;

class AutocloseableWrapper implements AutoCloseable {
    private FileReader r1;
    private FileReader r2;

    public AutocloseableWrapper(String path1, String path2) throws IOException {
        r1 = new FileReader(path1);
        r2 = new FileReader(path2);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        r1.close();
        r2.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (AutocloseableWrapper w = new AutocloseableWrapper("good-path", "bad-path")) {
                System.out.format("doing something\n");
                throw new IOException("doing something in main");
            }
    }
}
```

There are at least two issues with this wrapper:

1. If "bad-path" is invalid and causes the assignment to `r2` to throw, then `r1` is not closed.
2. If wrapper construction succeeds but then `r1.close` throws, then `r2` is not closed.

All those issues can be addressed, but then writing the wrapper becomes quite non-trivial and error-prone, even if wrapping only two resources:

```
import java.io.*;

class AutocloseableWrapper implements AutoCloseable {
    private FileReader r1;
    private FileReader r2;

    public AutocloseableWrapper(String path1, String path2) throws IOException {
        r1 = new FileReader(path1);
        try {
            r2 = new FileReader(path2);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                r1.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e2) {
                e.addSuppressed(e2);
            }
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        IOException e = null;
        try {
            r1.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e1) {
            e = e1;
        }

        try {
            r2.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e2) {
            if (e == null)
                throw e2;
            else {
                e.addSuppressed(e2);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (AutocloseableWrapper w = new AutocloseableWrapper("good-path", "bad-path")) {
                System.out.format("doing something\n");
                throw new IOException("doing something in main");
            }
    }
}
```

Is there some helper class or any other way to make writing wrappers easier?

Comment: Put the outer close in a finally so that thrown RuntimeExceptions don't also cause you to leak resources.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann, thank you for pointing out! This is one more reason why I'm frustrated at having to write wrappers like that.

Comment: @Paulo You should catch with the "catch-all" Throwable catch clause and then rethrow it.This would still work because of precise rethrow feature in Java7 exclusively introduced because of try-with-resources statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable the syntactic code unwrapped by the compiler....You can find the Oracle article over here :-
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html

Coming to the question,if you have a wrapper you can do something like this

```
@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    Throwable t = null;
    try {
        r1.close();
    } catch (Throwable t1) {
        t = t1;
        throw t1;
    } finally {
        if (t != null) {
            try {
                r2.close();
            } catch (Throwable t2) {
                t.addSuppressed(t2);
            }
        } else {

            r2.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:This will work because of precise rethrow feature in Java** 7

Comment: Thank you for the ref to the article. I can see that your code is much more correct than mine and that it follows the patterns that the compiler would generate for a try-with-resources according to the article. However, if I understood correctly, this is something we still will have to code by hand inside the close and constructor methods of the wrapper. Is that so?

Comment: @Paulo..In case of a wrapper,you already have the resources instantiated and therefore you would need to implement your own custom close method..However,If you need to instantiate resources and then close them,you can use try-with-resources and you would not have to implement your own close functionality

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generic resource wrapper such as:

```
public class CloseableChain implements AutoCloseable {
  private AutoCloseable r1;
  private CloseableChain r2;

  public void attach(AutoCloseable r) {
    if (r1 == null) {
      r1 = r;
    } else {
      if (r2 == null) {
        r2 = new CloseableChain();
      }
      r2.attach(r);
    }
  }

  public void close() throws Exception {
    if (r1 == null) {
      return;
    }
    Throwable t = null;
    try {
      r1.close();
    } catch (Throwable t1) {
      t = t1;
      throw t1;
    } finally {
      if (r2 != null) {
        if (t != null) {
          try {
            r2.close();
          } catch (Throwable t2) {
            t.addSuppressed(t2);
          }
        } else {
          r2.close();
        }
}}}}
```

Then you could refactor your code to:

```
import java.io.*;

class AutocloseableWrapper implements AutoCloseable {
  private CloseableChain chain;
  private FileReader r1;
  private FileReader r2;
  private FileReader r3;

  public AutocloseableWrapper(String path1, String path2) throws IOException {
    chain = new CloseableChain();
    r1 = new FileReader(path1);
    chain.attach(r1);
    r2 = new FileReader(path2);
    chain.attach(r2);
    // and even more...
    r3 = new FileReader("whatever");
    chain.attach(r3);
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws IOException {
    chain.close();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (AutocloseableWrapper w = new AutocloseableWrapper("good", "bad")) {
      System.out.format("doing something\n");
      throw new IOException("doing something in main");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Very nice indeed, @coding.mof! It happened to me that I in fact started exploring this approach more thoroughly ever since I started pondering on the issue. Please, allow me here to shamelessly plug [my own take at that](https://github.com/prosoft-nearshore/Java-Scopes).